# Stuck on Group by query duplicating rows

Tags: oracle, group-by, pivot

I have the following query in Oracle where I am trying to show a count of inventory coming in and out per month.  The output is supposed to look like a score card with the months being the column headers.

```
Part Nbr   part desc    Type    Jan   Feb   March ....
11111      some part     IN      2    5     20
11111      some part     OUT     30   10    5
```

But I am ending up with an output as such. For every month I add, I get more duplicates.

```
Part Nbr   Part Description                Type    Jan     Feb
11291     UMTS TMA  AWS/AWS w/ VSWR         OUT     9       32
11291     UMTS TMA  AWS/AWS w/ VSWR          IN    247      32
11291     UMTS TMA  AWS/AWS w/ VSWR         OUT     9       29
11291     UMTS TMA  AWS/AWS w/ VSWR          IN    247      29
11291     UMTS TMA  AWS/AWS w/ VSWR         OUT     9       32
11291     UMTS TMA  AWS/AWS w/ VSWR          IN    247      32
11291     UMTS TMA  AWS/AWS w/ VSWR         OUT     9       29
11291     UMTS TMA  AWS/AWS w/ VSWR          IN    247      29
```

I have tried putting Max around my type and the months and that does reduce the duplicates but it also eliminates the Out results.

For my query, I decided to keep it simple (for me) in the sense that I do subqueries for every month and then do a select of the subqueries. I looked at Pivot, but was hung up on how to do the pivoting.

```
SELECT a.part_nbr as part_nbr, a.part_desc as part_desc,  b.InvType as "Type",b.recv_qty_1 as "January", c.recv_qty_2 as "February" FROM
(
SELECT part_nbr, part_desc
FROM tmadmin.customer_product
) a,
(
SELECT recv_part_nbr, SUM(inv_qty) as recv_qty_1, 'IN' as InvType
FROM tmadmin.ro_hist a
WHERE trunc(recv_date,'MM') = trunc(To_Date('01-01-2014', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 'MM')
GROUP BY recv_part_nbr
UNION
SELECT x.pack_part_nbr, SUM(z.inv_qty) as ship_qty_1, 'OUT' as InvType
FROM tmadmin.ship_dtl x, tmadmin.ship_hdr y, tmadmin.ro_hist z
WHERE x.pack_nbr = y.pack_nbr
AND x.pack_asset_tag = z.asset_tag
AND trunc(y.ship_date,'MM') = trunc(To_Date('01-01-2014', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 'MM')
GROUP BY x.pack_part_nbr
) b,
(
SELECT recv_part_nbr, SUM(inv_qty) as recv_qty_2, 'IN' as InvType
FROM tmadmin.ro_hist a
WHERE trunc(recv_date,'MM') = add_months(trunc(To_Date('01-01-2014', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 'MM'),1)
GROUP BY recv_part_nbr
UNION
SELECT x.pack_part_nbr, SUM(z.inv_qty) as ship_qty_2, 'OUT' as InvType
FROM tmadmin.ship_dtl x, tmadmin.ship_hdr y, tmadmin.ro_hist z
WHERE x.pack_nbr = y.pack_nbr
AND x.pack_asset_tag = z.asset_tag
AND trunc(y.ship_date,'MM') = add_months(trunc(To_Date('01-01-2014', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 'MM'),1)
GROUP BY x.pack_part_nbr
) c,
(
SELECT recv_part_nbr, SUM(inv_qty) as recv_qty_3, 'IN' as InvType
FROM tmadmin.ro_hist a
WHERE trunc(recv_date,'MM') = add_months(trunc(To_Date('01-01-2014', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 'MM'),2)
GROUP BY recv_part_nbr
UNION
SELECT x.pack_part_nbr, SUM(z.inv_qty) as ship_qty_3, 'OUT' as InvType
FROM tmadmin.ship_dtl x, tmadmin.ship_hdr y, tmadmin.ro_hist z
WHERE x.pack_nbr = y.pack_nbr
AND x.pack_asset_tag = z.asset_tag
AND trunc(y.ship_date,'MM') = add_months(trunc(To_Date('01-01-2014', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 'MM'),2)
GROUP BY x.pack_part_nbr
) d
WHERE a.part_nbr = b.recv_part_nbr(+)
AND a.part_nbr = c.recv_part_nbr(+)
AND a.part_nbr = d.recv_part_nbr(+)
order by part_nbr
```

Addendum: I tried to use pivot and I am getting an error SQL jcommand not properly ended.

```
select * from (
SELECT recv_part_nbr, a.inv_qty,  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM a.recv_date) as mth
FROM tmadmin.ro_hist a
WHERE trunc(recv_date,'MM') >= trunc(To_Date('01-01-2014', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 'MM')
AND trunc(recv_date,'MM') <= trunc(To_Date('31-12-2014', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 'MM')
UNION
SELECT x.pack_part_nbr, z.inv_qty, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM y.ship_date)  as mth 
FROM tmadmin.ship_dtl x, tmadmin.ship_hdr y, tmadmin.ro_hist z
WHERE x.pack_nbr = y.pack_nbr
AND x.pack_asset_tag = z.asset_tag
AND trunc(y.ship_date,'MM') >= trunc(To_Date('01-01-2014', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 'MM')
AND trunc(y.ship_date,'MM') <= trunc(To_Date('31-12-2014', 'dd-mm-yyyy'), 'MM')
)
PIVOT
(
    SUM(a.inv_qty)  as "IN",
    SUM(z.inv_qty)  as "OUT"
    FOR (mth)
    IN (1 AS January,
          2 AS February,
          3 AS March,
          4 AS April,
          5 AS May,
          6 AS June,
          7 AS July,
          8 AS August,
          9 AS September,
          10 AS October,
          11 AS November,
          12 AS December)
);
```

Comment: Post table ddl, some sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

It's not about the grouping. You're getting duplicates because you aren't joining on `InvType`; but you can't outer join to more than one table so you need a different mechanism. One option is to have another dummy table that generates the two possible values, something like:

```
SELECT a.part_nbr as part_nbr, a.part_desc as part_desc, a.InvType as "Type",
  b.recv_qty_1 as "January", c.recv_qty_2 as "February"
FROM
(
  SELECT part_nbr, part_desc, InvType
  FROM tmadmin.customer_product,
  (
    SELECT 'IN' as InvType from dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'OUT' as Invtype from dual
  )
) a,
...
WHERE a.part_nbr = b.recv_part_nbr(+)
AND a.InvType = b.Invtype (+)
WHERE a.part_nbr = c.recv_part_nbr(+)
AND a.InvType = c.Invtype (+)
WHERE a.part_nbr = d.recv_part_nbr(+)
AND a.InvType = d.Invtype (+)
```

[Here's an SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/27544) if what I think you're seeing, with fake data clearly as you haven't posted DDL or insert statements to recreate your actual problem. The first query gets duplicates in the same kind of pattern you do; the second uses this method to let you outer join on two columns.

Although I'd rather see it with ANSI joins; a `cross join` within `a`, and then `left outer joins` between `a` and `b`, `c` and `d` instead of the old Oracle-specific syntax. (With my fake data, [like this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/27545)). That's not really the point of the question though.

This also seems like a painful way to achieve this; you'll end up with 12 subqueries for a full year, presumably. A single subquery with the month in the `group by` and then a `pivot` would be easier to read and maintain...

If you're on 11g and have access to the `pivot` operator you do this, I think:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT cp.part_nbr as part_nbr, cp.part_desc as part_desc,
    it.inv_type, t.mnth, t.inv_qty
  FROM (
      SELECT 'IN' as inv_type FROM dual
      UNION ALL select 'OUT' as inv_type from dual
  ) it
  CROSS JOIN customer_product cp
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT extract(month from recv_date) as mnth, recv_part_nbr as part_nbr,
      inv_qty,
      'IN' as inv_type
    FROM ro_hist a
    WHERE recv_date >= date '2014-01-01'
    AND recv_date < date '2015-01-01'
    UNION
    SELECT extract(month from y.ship_date) as mnth, x.pack_part_nbr as part_nbr,
      z.inv_qty, 'OUT' as inv_type
    FROM ship_dtl x, ship_hdr y, ro_hist z
    WHERE x.pack_nbr = y.pack_nbr
    AND x.pack_asset_tag = z.asset_tag
    AND y.ship_date >= date '2014-01-01'
    AND y.ship_date < date '2015-01-01'
  ) t
  ON t.part_nbr = cp.part_nbr
  AND t.inv_type = it.inv_type
)
PIVOT (SUM(inv_qty) AS qty FOR (mnth) IN (1 as Jan, 2 as Feb, 3 as Mar));
```

... just adding more `IN` clauses for the rest of the year. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/75906/3) using dummy data that matches your duplicated example (I think!).

If you aren't on 11g you can do a pivot the old-fashioned way:

```
SELECT cp.part_nbr as part_nbr, cp.part_desc as part_desc, it.inv_type,
  sum(case when t.mnth = 1 then t.inv_qty else 0 end) as Jan,
  sum(case when t.mnth = 2 then t.inv_qty else 0 end) as Feb,
  sum(case when t.mnth = 3 then t.inv_qty else 0 end) as Mar
FROM (
    SELECT 'IN' as inv_type FROM dual
    UNION ALL select 'OUT' as inv_type from dual
) it
CROSS JOIN customer_product cp
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT extract(month from recv_date) as mnth, recv_part_nbr as part_nbr,
    inv_qty, 'IN' as inv_type
  FROM ro_hist a
  WHERE recv_date >= date '2014-01-01'
  AND recv_date < date '2015-01-01'
  UNION
  SELECT extract(month from y.ship_date) as mnth, x.pack_part_nbr as part_nbr,
    z.inv_qty, 'OUT' as inv_type
  FROM ship_dtl x, ship_hdr y, ro_hist z
  WHERE x.pack_nbr = y.pack_nbr
  AND x.pack_asset_tag = z.asset_tag
  AND y.ship_date >= date '2014-01-01'
  AND y.ship_date < date '2015-01-01'
) t
ON t.part_nbr = cp.part_nbr
AND t.inv_type = it.inv_type
GROUP BY cp.part_nbr, cp.part_desc, it.inv_type;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/75906/4) with the same data. Again, just add more `sum(case())` clauses for the rest of the months.

Comment: I agree with the pivot but I was getting hung up on the syntax and how to achieve the pivot.  I spent a little time searching online, but not enough.  Yes...this is going to be an ugly query when all said and done.

Comment: But each subquery is identical apart from the `add_months()`, right?

Comment: @user3308606 - I've added a stab at a pivot, assuming you're on 11g so have it available. This only has one subquery with a date range (open-ended in the example). You can tweak the `mnth` values to be the month name or abbreviation or number I suppose, to make it year-agnostic - then you'd just need to change the date range in the inner query, but would have to make sure it was constrained to a single year. Might be way off what you really need of course...

Comment: Thanks for the Pivot example.  I thought we were using 11g, but I was corrected by our DBA that the project I am working on is version 10.2.0.4.  So I went with your other example on joining the  type and it worked.  Appreciate the help.

Comment: @user3308606 - OK, before 11g you can use `sum(case())` and `group by` to get the same effect; example added to answer.